# Best practices for creating views or separate lists?

Tags: list, best-practices, aggregation

Is there a best practice that can be said for whether to add a tag and have users filter on it or just create a separate list?

We have many groups in our SharePoint application that all have many projects underneath them.  We approached the problem by creating a tag for each project so they can have a master list of tasks / issues / documents that they can quickly switch between.  But more and more users are asking to just create separate lists per project, effectively removing the need for the tag but increasing complexity as they now have to navigate to the different lists to see each project's items.  Using separate lists feels like folders and loses the ease with which users can quickly change a view.

Is it a pipe dream to have users all use one list and tag things or should we just accept the bloat of having a list per project?

Comment: how many people in each group? is their any permission restriction that one group cannot see other group's project etc? what is the size of site collections, how many items in the list?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Each group can vary from 10 to 30 people.  No permission restrictions, if you are in the group, you can see all projects.  Site collection currently is under 2 gigs.  List size is small right now, under 200 items per list, but I could see that growing.

Comment: how many groups?

Comment: There are currently 12 groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i Understand that you make a decision between seprate List or views. Here is you requirement what i get.

- No unique permission
- 12 Groups only
- Not too much List items

I would go with one List so that keep things simple. I will have atleaset two Column, one for Group name and 2nd for the Project name/number. Both can be MMS columns.

I will build views on the bases of the groups name column in order to live under the List view Threshold.

Or.

You can create the seprate List for each group, this give you more granular control in case if you want implement unique permissions in future.

Answer (score 0):

Normally each Project will have their own site where project members can collaborate. It should have a task list, document library etc.

Now from your use case using a single list is not a good idea, because as more projects are added the list will grow and the unique permissions grow. This make bad performance as well as clutter the navigation.

Comment: So each group has between 10 and 30 projects going on.  Each project would get its own subsite?

Comment: Yes. That is how I recently implemented for one of my client. The structure will be like Company->Department->BU->Project1/Project2 etc. All projects will be subsites under BU (in your case it might be different)